# Finding the steady state and stability of this system:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

$$\frac {dy_1}{dt}=-ry_{1}\ln\left(\dfrac{y_1}{a+by_{2}}\right)$$

$$\frac{dy_2}{dt}=-ry_{2}\ln\left(\dfrac{y_2}{c+dy_{1}}\right)$$

I've been trying since forever. I see the trivial solution but how do I find my logarithmic zeroes and represent it in terms of (y1*,y2*)?

Comment: How did you approach this? I'm having trouble reaching this. EDIT: Okay I got it. How do I check if it's linearly stable?

Comment: Yes, my Ys are positive or zero and my a,b,c,d are positive.